# selenium witn ruby cannot open a web browser

Tags: ruby, eclipse, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, selenium3

I am using `selenium webdriver` with Ruby, and I am not able to open any browser. I have added the chromedriver path in system variable.  Tried with firefox and IE also.

This is what my code looks like:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver=Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

The error i am getting is 
in `<main>': undefined method`get` for Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: Try the first example on https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings.  Works for me (win7 + `selenium-webdriver (3.0.0.beta3.1)` + firefox 49.0.1 with latest geckodriver).  YMMV.

Comment: it worked when i set the path as system variable.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver` class instead.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> driver = Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for(:chrome)
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0xd1f4bb08 browser=:chrome>
```

Comment: i tried it  and the code isdriver=Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for:chrome.driver_path='C:\\Users\\Jerin\\Downloads\\rubygems-2.6.7\\rubygems-2.6.7\\bin\\chromedriver.exe'

Comment: Getting another error "in `<main>': undefined method `driver_path=' for :chrome:Symbol (NoMethodError)"

Comment: When i used 'Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for(:chrome)' in irb, it worked fine .But the same script in eclipse is throwing error "driver_path':         Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from        http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html ".

Comment: I have the chromedriver path set in the system variable.

Comment: someone please help. i cant move forward without this

Comment: What about from cmd? What happens if you run say `ruby.exe chrome_script.rb` ?

Comment: i tried the script which you mentioned above from irb and it worked fine. irb(main):002:0> driver=Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for(:chrome)
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..fc3642078 browser=:chrome>